# VBScript - need to query on two different paths for getting the list of installed program

Tags: vbscript

i am kinda newbie for vbscript. i am working to get the list of all programs using vbscript through registry. My problem is I want to search on two paths which is `"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"`  and `"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\`"  then compile it to one `CSV`.

**Here is my code:**

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim strComputer, strKeyPath,strKeyPath2
strComputer = "." 


Sub Check_Installed(strKeyPath)
  Dim objReg, strSubkey, arrSubkeys 

  Set objReg=GetObject( _ 
      "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
     strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

  objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys 

  Dim objFSO, objCSVFile

  Const ForWriting = 2

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  Set objCSVFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Installed-Softwares_final.csv", _ 
      ForWriting, True)

  Dim Name,Version,Publisher,Location,Size

  For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys 
   objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayName" , Name
   If Name <> "" Then 
      objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayVersion", Version
             objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "Publisher",Publisher
             objReg.GetDWORDValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "EstimatedSize" , Size
    If  Size <> "" Then 
     Size= Round(Size/1024, 3) & " MB" 
    Else 
     Size= "0 MB"
    End If 

             objCSVFile.Write Name &","&Version&","&Publisher&","&Size
             objCSVFile.Writeline ' New Line
        End If 
  Next 

End Sub


strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\" 
strKeyPath2 = "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

Check_Installed(strKeyPath)
Check_Installed(strKeyPath2)

WScript.Echo "Installed Softwares exported successfully into CSV file through Registry using VBScript."
WScript.Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my standard answer. Use `/format:csv` for CSV output.

*Start - All Programs - Accessories* - Right click Command Prompt and choose *Run As Administrator*. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste). Type for table format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:htable
```

or in a form format

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsInstaller.html" product get /format:hform
```

It will create a html file on the desktop.

**Note**

This is not a full list. This is only products installed with Windows Installer. There is no feature for everything.

However as I said in my previous post nearly everything is listed in the registry.

So to see it in a command prompt

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s
```

or in a file

```
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s>"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUninstall.txt"
```

To see it in notepad in a different format

Click *Start - All Programs - Accessories* - Right click Command Prompt and choose *Run As Administrator*. Type *Regedit* and navigate to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Right click the Uninstall key and choose Export. If you save as a reg file (there is also text file, they are slightly different text formats) you need to right click the file and choose Edit to view it.

To view Windows Updates

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\WindowsUpdate.html" qfe  get /format:htable
```

The same in VBS is (which means the best way is batch).

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Product")

For Each objItem in colItems
    msgbox objItem.Name & " " & objItem.Version
Next
```

Comment: thank you for the answer Noodles but my boss wants a executable file to get all the installed program on 1 click. im not into coding thats why im looking for help here. :D

Comment: Neither batch nor script are "executables".